# Javascript: Check if function is TRUE

Tags: javascript, titanium

i have a function, which should return TRUE, when IF condition inside FOR cyklus is met. (i tested that condition, it works)

```
createBtn.addEventListener('click',function (e){

var ch = function check(){
var url = "http://hotel.010.sk/skyfit/read.php";
var json, poc, vypis;
var i=0;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
    json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


        for (i = 0; i < json.poc.length; i++) {

            prnt = json.poc[i];  

            if(win.xtra_id == prnt.id_cv && picker.getSelectedRow(0).title == prnt.datum && prnt.capacity <= prnt.cnt ){

                return true;
            }

        };

    }

});


xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();             

};

...
```

But when i call function here to check it turns me always **true**, unless IF condition in check() is not met!

```
if(ch){

alert('Something');       
}
```

How to fix my function to get TRUE only when my condition is met?

Thanks.

Comment: first set variable having value false. Then update as true when condition is reached . return that variable from function

Comment: the function doesn't wait the end of the inner ajax call, but it returns immediately, that's why your condition is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression

```
if (ch) {
```

is always true, because `ch` is a function and `ToBoolean(function) === true`.

However even if you changed it to `if (ch()) {..}` it would not work anyway, because inside of the function you perform asynchronous operation. Function just returns without waiting for it to finish. In this case you should use callbacks or promise patters. Simplest is callback.

```
var ch = function check(callback) {

    // ...

    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function () {
            json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var status = false;
            for (i = 0; i < json.poc.length; i++) {
                prnt = json.poc[i];
                if (win.xtra_id == prnt.id_cv && picker.getSelectedRow(0).title == prnt.datum && prnt.capacity <= prnt.cnt) {
                    status = true;
                }
            };
            callback(status);
        }
    });

    // ...
};

ch(function(status) {
    if (status) {
        alert('Something')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following thing to check condition should always **true**

```
while(true){
    alert('something');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function, `ch` has no return value! It launches the `Ti.Network.createHTTPClient` function where you define an anonymous callback function (`onload: function(){...`). That anonymous function is executed *after* the ch has already returned. You'll need to either check your conditional after the callback:

```
...
                         if (win.xtra_id == prnt.id_cv && picker.getSelectedRow(0).title == prnt.datum && prnt.capacity <= prnt.cnt) {
                             alert('something') //DO YOUR STUFF HERE!
                             return true;
                         }
...
```

***or*** wait for the callback to happen before you check the conditional using some global flags:

```
var MYFLAG=-1

...
                         if (win.xtra_id == prnt.id_cv && picker.getSelectedRow(0).title == prnt.datum && prnt.capacity <= prnt.cnt) {
                             MYFLAG=1
                             return true;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             MYFLAG=0
                         }
...

//use a timer to check the flag every 500ms
var myInterval = setInterval(function()
    {     
    if (MYFLAG != -1) {
        if (MYFLAG==1) {
            alert('returned true :)');
        }
        else {
            alert('did not return true :(');
        }

        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}, 500);
```